# Identifying a page element for Selenium automation

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a Application Under Test that has a tabular structure like below:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-color: White">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="lefthandcol" class="b24-lefthandcol" valign="top" style="width: 130px !important">
<td style="height: 400px; width: 5px">
<td style="height: 400px; width: 5px">
<td valign="top">
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MiddlePanel">
<div id="DestinationDiv"></div>
<table>
</td>
<td style="height: 400px; width: 5px">
<td style="height: 400px; width: 5px">
<td width="225" valign="top" align="right" style="background-color: White;">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The question is how do I identify this table since it doesn't have `id`?

What is generally people do in such scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You should find any unique parent-children relationship and write it with the help of CSS or Xpath:

```
IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[descendant::*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MiddlePanel']]"));
```

So the table with descendant element with `id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MiddlePanel` will be found.

Answer (score 1):

If id is not available then either go with xpath or css.If you cant write them by your own then you can use tools like firebug and xpath checker..